# Is it possible to include a phtml file from another module in my template in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, template, phtml

I'm making a Megamenu Module, where I want to include the phtml of a file in my MailChimp module (Signup Form). Is there a way I can call on this template from within another module?

Comment: which magento version are you using ?

Comment: Please specify magento version

Comment: Sorry I forgot! Question is edited with the version.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely, you can call any PHTML file from another PHTML file or layout file:

To call phtml from phtml file, use below syntax:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Namespace\Module\Block\BlockClass")->setTemplate("Namespace_Module::filename.phtml")->toHtml();
```

or you can even try:

```
<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Namespace_Module::/foldername/filename.phtml')) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can include / add other's module template in different module. in your module's layout file add block like that :

```
 <block class="other\module\block\class" name="mail.chimp.template" template="Mail_Chimp::template.phtml" />
```

here :

> class="other\module\block\class", will be other module block class.
>
> template = "Module_Name/template_file.phtml"

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. In your layout xml, specify the module
see below (where vendor i will assume it's MailChimp:

```
<block class="YourBlock" name="your.name" template="Vendor_module::path/template.phtml" >
```